# Pasar informacion de un formulario hijo a un formulario padre Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola tengo un componente padre que tiene un formulario y tengo un formulario hijo el cual es un mapa y que al darle click me da las coordenadas donde el usuario dio el click. Tengo el html del componente padre de esta forma.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <input formControlName="name" type="name" required>
 <input formControlName="email" type="email" required>
 <app-map [parentForm]="form"></app-map>         
 <button [disabled]=!form.valid (click)="OnSubmit()">
</form>
```

Y mi archivo ts de mi componente padre

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name : ['',Validators.required],
      email : ['',Validators.required]
    }) 
  }
  OnSubmit() {
    console.log('Enviado');
  }
```

Y ahora mi componente hijo, estoy utilzando mapbox por lo cual el html no es un input sino mas bien un div con un id, la cual mapbox ya tiene las funciones necesarias para tomar las coordenadas con un click de esta forma.

HTML

```
<div id="mapa" (mouseenter)="getCoords($event)"></div>
```

TS

```
@Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
      lat: Validators.required,
      long: Validators.required
    })
  }

  getCoords(){
    // Funcion de click de mapbox para obtener las coordenadas al hacer click
    this.mapa.on('click', (e) => {
      this.parentForm.controls.lat.setValue(e.lngLat.lat);
      this.parentForm.controls.long.setValue(e.lngLat.lng);
    })
  }
```

Como podria pasarle a mi componente padre el formulario de **parentForm** o en su defecto los datos de **lat** y **long**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Angular un FormGroup implementa la interfaz FormControl, así que son anidables:

```
this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
  lat: Validators.required,
  long: Validators.required,
  nestedForm: this.fb.group({
    lat: Validators.required,
    long: Validators.required
  })
});
```

De este modo puedes pasar a otro componente parte de tu form:

```
<app-map [parentForm]="form.get('nestedForm')"></app-map>
```

Y el padre además puede observar cualquier cambio en el formulario.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcionando: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-form-pawer13?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Y como quedaria el formulario padre? Le estoy intentado hacer un `console.log(this.form.get('nestedForm'))` y me aparece como null

Comment: Te he puesto un ejemplo en stackblitz para que lo veas funcionando